# StrongSwan outputs in log "certificate status is not available"

Tags: strongswan

Wha does the warning `certificate status is not available` in `charon.log` mean?

```
16[CFG] certificate status is not available
16[CFG]   reached self-signed root ca with a path length of 0
```

Everything works, I just want to understand what it means.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that strongSwan was not able to verify the status of the certificate with either a [Certificate Revocation List (CRL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revocation_list) or via the [Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol). Both methods can be used to revoke previously issued certificates. If *strictcrlpolicy* in `ipsec.conf` is set to *yes* or *ifuri* strongSwan will only accept certificates if the status has been verified, the default is *no* so you will just get this log message.

If you want to use one or both of these methods you have to create a CRL or setup an OCSP server and then either configure the CRL or OCSP URIs in a [*ca* section](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/CaSection) in `ipsec.conf`, or make sure your certificates contain the URIs in *CRL Distribution Point* or *Authority Information Access* X.509 extensions.
For smaller setups this is usually not required, though.